# snowflake - copy delimiter error character "\" in the date itself like "BOB\Y", so data copy error

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm unable to use copy and load data into snowflake table.

> error-- Field delimiter ',' found while expecting record delimiter
>   '\n' File 'txn_type_text.csv.gz', line 690, character 35 Row 689,
>   column "TRIPS_TRANS_TEXT"["TRIPS_TRANS_DESC":3]

any help!

[image]

Comment: Your title and error description do not seem to match.

Comment: The error message appears to indicate that the comma is your field delimiter.  It is likely found inside a value somewhere.  Do you have your fields optionally enclosed by a character to allow the comma to exist in your data?

Comment: Can you try with field optionally enclosed by option in copy command. If possible please share sample record. Many Thanks,
Sriga

Comment: If you still need help, please send your file format and a row of sample data would help us to see how you are separating your fields.

Answer (score 0):

It is late reply but may help others who sees it.

If the `field_delimiter(,)` we define for the CSV also appears in the record, then this error will appear. Normally, CSV files will wrap such records in `"` (you can see this by opening the CSV file in a text editor).

Use `FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '"'` in Copy statement. This will take care of extra delimiter available in record itself.